# Where can I get list of websites features, which have made websites a great experience? Example : sliders to perform a search in a range

Tags: web-development, website-features

Where can I get list of websites features? Example : sliders to perform a search in a range.

more... Examples: a feature like tagging

a feature like add to shopping cart

a feature like voting up a question or voting down. like i stack exchange sites

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if you're planning on stuffing half of whatever list it is that someone comes up with onto your site, that won't necessarily make your site a great experience.

Comment: I am not talking about stuffing. I need them for my inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo! Design Pattern Library currently lists [59 User Interface Patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) divided under the following categories - Layout, Navigation, Selection, Rich interaction, Social

Comment: Thanks for reminding us of this -- i had forgotten it existed!